# How do I import a mySQL file to my Android program?

Tags: android, mysql, import

I have an app which creates and updates it's own MySQL database. I now want to allow the user to export a copy of the database (for backup purposes) and then at a later date import the file again. I have no need to change the format of the database during this process.

I'm not sure about the best/simplest way to do this. I have been able to get my app to export the databases to the SD card using the code below, but the question is - how can I get my app to import this file again?

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//"+ packageName +"//databases//"+ class_dbname; //dbList[0];
            String backupDBPath = "//data//"+ class_dbname; //dbList[0];
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
```

Comment: Better save database in sdcard and use database from sdcard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing it on this way:

```
     public boolean importDatabase(String dbPath) throws IOException {
    // Close the SQLiteOpenHelper so it will commit the created empty
    // database to internal storage.
    close();
    File newDb = new File(dbPath);
    File oldDb = new File(DB_FILEPATH);
    if (newDb.exists()) {
        FileUtils.copyFile(new FileInputStream(newDb), new FileOutputStream(oldDb));
        // Access the copied database so SQLiteHelper will cache it and mark
        // it as created.
        DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And "copyFile()" method is:

```
public static void copyFile(FileInputStream fromFile, FileOutputStream toFile) throws IOException {
    FileChannel fromChannel = null;
    FileChannel toChannel = null;
    try {
        fromChannel = fromFile.getChannel();
        toChannel = toFile.getChannel();
        fromChannel.transferTo(0, fromChannel.size(), toChannel);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fromChannel != null) {
                fromChannel.close();
            }
        } finally {
            if (toChannel != null) {
                toChannel.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards